# Pytest Flask Request Referrer

Tags: python, testing, flask, integration-testing, pytest

I'm currently testing my Flask application using Pytest and ran into a problem with a POST request and a redirect.  Let me explain a bit more.

A user wants to register for our new site, but must confirm they have an account with a different site.  Once they confirm the credentials of the other account, they are taken to the register page.  They can **only** hit the register page if coming from the confirmation page else they are redirected back to the home page.

I want to test this functionality and can successfully make a POST request to the confirmation page.  If I don't specify `follow_redirects=True` and print the response data, I get the following HTML:

```
  Redirecting...

  Redirecting...
  You should be redirected automatically to target URL: /register?emp_id=1.  If not click the link.
```

Great!  Exactly what I'm looking for!  I want to be redirected to the registration page.

Now when I do specify `follow_redirects=True` and print out the response data, I expected the register page HTML to return.  The response data instead returns the home page HTML.

I further investigated where the problem was.  As I mentioned before, the **only** way you can hit the registration page is from the confirmation page.  I took a look at the `request.referrer` attribute in the view during the test and it will return `None`.  I attempted setting the `Referrer` header content in the test's POST request, but to no luck.

Here is the code I'm working with:

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/confirm', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def confirm_bpm():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = BPMLoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        bpm_user = BPMUser.query\
            .filter(and_(BPMUser.group_name == form.group_name.data,
                         BPMUser.user_name == form.username.data,
                         BPMUser.password == encrypt(form.password.data)))\
            .first()
        if not bpm_user:
            flash('BPM user account does not exist!')
            url = url_for('confirm_bpm')
            return redirect(url)
        if bpm_user.user_level != 3:
            flash('Only L3 Users can register through this portal.')
            url = url_for('confirm_bpm')
            return redirect(url)
        url = url_for('register', emp_id=bpm_user.emp_id)
        return redirect(url)
    return render_template('login/confirm_bpm.html', form=form)

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if request.method == 'GET' and\
            request.referrer != request.url_root + 'confirm':
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    emp_id = request.args.get('emp_id')
    emp_id_exists = User.query.filter_by(emp_id=emp_id).first()
    if emp_id_exists:
        flash('User is already registered!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = User(login_type=form.login_type.data, login=form.login.data,
                        emp_id=emp_id)
        new_user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Registration successful!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login/register.html', form=form)
```

### **TESTS**

**base.py**

```
from config import TestConfig
from app import app, db

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    """
    Initializes test requests for each individual test.  The test request
    keeps track of cookies.
    """
    app.config.from_object(TestConfig)

    client = app.test_client()
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield client

    ctx.pop()


def confirm_bpm_login(client, group_name, username, password):
    """
    POST to /confirm
    """
    return client.post('/confirm', data=dict(
        group_name=group_name,
        username=username,
        password=password,
        submit=True
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

**test_auth.py**

```
from app import db
from app.models import BPMCompany, BPMEmployee, User, BPMUser

from tests.base import client, db_data, login, confirm_bpm_login

def test_registration_page_from_confirm(client, db_data):
    """
    Test registration page by HTTP GET request  from "/confirm" url.
    Should cause redirect to registration page.

    !!! FAILING !!!
    Reason: The POST to /confirm will redirect us to /register?emp_id=1,
    but it will return the index.html because in the register view,
    request.referrer does not recognize the POST is coming from /confirm_bpm
    """
    bpm_user = BPMUser.query.filter_by(id=1).first()

    rv = confirm_bpm_login(client, bpm_user.group_name,
                           bpm_user.user_name, 'jsmith01')

    assert b'Register' in rv.data
```

The `db_data` parameter is a fixture in **base.py** that just populates the DB with the necessary data for the registration flow to work.

My goal is to test a complete registration flow without having to separate the confirmation and registration into two tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Flask test client does not appear to add the `Referer` header when it follows redirects.

What you can do is implement your own version of following redirects. Maybe something like this:

```
def confirm_bpm_login(client, group_name, username, password):
    """
    POST to /confirm
    """
    response = client.post('/confirm', data=dict(
        group_name=group_name,
        username=username,
        password=password,
        submit=True
    ), follow_redirects=False)
    if 300 <= response.status_code < 400:
        response = client.get(response.headers['Location'], headers={
            "Referer": 'http://localhost/confirm'
        })
    return response
```

Please test this, I wrote it from memory and may need some minor adjustments.

Comment: This did the trick.  Ran into the issue where I misspelled `Referer` and didn't receive a proper redirect lol.  I previously mentioned setting the `Referer` header in the POST, but sounds like I put it on the wrong HTTP action.  Thanks for clearing this up Miguel.